# Embed graphical editor to a web page

Tags: web-apps, library, html, framework, graphic-design

I am creating a web page and I need to add a component that allows a user who enters my web to graphically edit an 3d model in order to create custom designs using a GUI. Paint, add shapes, colors, images ...

I have searched on google and I don't see anything, do you know if there is any framework or library that allows me this for 3d model or 2d models if there is no choice?

For example:

I want to add a GUI on my website similar to the orange square that allows the user to edit the cup
[image: 3d gui editor example]

I would be grateful for anything to start at least. Thank you.